# Cannot resolve symbol Obserable.onSubscribe in rxjava

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

as i am new to `RxJava` trying to run following code but its showing me

```
Cannot resolve symbol `Obserable.onSubscribe`
```

code is as follow

```
Observable<String> fetchFromGoogle = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {
                try {

                }catch(Exception e){
                    subscriber.onError(e); // In case there are network errors
                }
            }
        });
```

[image]

have added following entries in `gradle`

```
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.8'
```

for java 8 compatibility

```
 compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

Comment: You are depending on RxJava 2 but the code example is for RxJava 1. There is no `Observable.OnSubscribe` in v2 and you are not supposed to call `create(OnSubscribe)` either as it is deprecated for being unsafe.

Comment: alrite , that means most of the tutorial over web is in RxJava1 :) that leads to me to this confusion , thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the comments:

You are depending on RxJava 2 but the code example is for RxJava 1. There is no Observable.OnSubscribe in v2 and you are not supposed to call create(OnSubscribe) either as it is deprecated for being unsafe.

If you wanted an RxJava 1 dependency:

```
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.3.4'
```

If you wanted RxJava 2 code:

```
io.reactivex.Observable<String> fetchFromGoogle = io.reactivex.Observable.create(
    new ObservableOnSubscribe<String>() {
        @Override
        public void subscribe(ObservableEmitter<String> emitter) {
            try {

            } catch(Exception e) {
                emitter.onError(e); // In case there are network errors
            }
        }
    });
```